# Android Webview shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is not called for base64 image data URL

Tags: android, html, image, webview

In my WebView it loads a webpage that includes a link to download an image with base64 data:

```
<a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64data}" download="fileName.jpg" target="_blank">Download Image</a>
```

In Chrome when it's clicked, it will download the image as a JPG file. But it doesn't work in Android WebView.

[Download Images using android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379174/download-images-using-android-webview) indicates that I should use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` to trigger the download.

It works with the image URL like `http://.../image.jpg`. But for my base 64 data URL, it only works on Android versions below 4.4, the method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is never called on Android 4.4+ because it has to be a valid URL according to the [Android API Guides](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html).

So my question is, why  `data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64data}` is not a valid URL in this case? What should I do to trigger `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` for the base64 data URL? (Or even by making changes on the webpage)

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated, all I need is to save the image in Android.

Comment: Think that the href should start with a protocol notation. Try data://.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to trigger `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` for your data: URI, simply remove the `download="fileName.jpg" target="_blank"` part from your `<a>` tag.

Actually, it's the `download` attribute that prevents `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` from being called, but having `target="_blank"` doesn't help anything, so it should be removed, too. You just need to return `true` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to avoid WebView actually navigating to the image link.

I guess, the explanation for this behavior is that images are handled by WebView internally, and thus they are not considered for downloading, see
[DownloadListener doesn't download images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746077/downloadlistener-doesnt-download-images) But I agree that it's a bit odd that having the `download` attribute worked prior to KitKat.

But then the next problem you'll face when following the advice from [Download Images using android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379174/download-images-using-android-webview) is that `DownloadManager` doesn't work with data: URIs :) What you can do instead is just transform that base64-encoded image using [Base64 utils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) into a binary blob, and save it yourself -- this way, you'll effectively get your image downloaded.